# Flutter – how to solve delete problem TextInputFormatter

Tags: flutter

My input is working perfectly, but I can't delete symbols. How to do this?

I just want the Date in the credit card formatted (like this: 01/25) And if 1 symbol > 1 I write 0+symbol, else I write just symbol

Here the code

```
class DateFormat extends TextInputFormatter {
  //Formatting to *#/## (if (*>1) *=0)
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    final newTextLength = newValue.text.length;
    int selectionIndex = newValue.selection.end;
    int usedSubstringIndex = 1;
    final newTextBuffer = StringBuffer();

    if (newTextLength >= 1) {
      if (newValue.text.startsWith(RegExp(r'[2-9]'))) {
        newTextBuffer.write('0${newValue.text.substring(0, 1)}');
        if (newValue.selection.end >= 1) selectionIndex++;
      } else {
        newTextBuffer.write(newValue.text.substring(0, 2));
      }
    }

    if (newTextLength >= 3) {
      newTextBuffer.write('/' + newValue.text.substring(2, usedSubstringIndex = 3));
      if (newValue.selection.end >= 2) selectionIndex++;
    }
    // Dump the rest.
    if (newTextLength > usedSubstringIndex) newTextBuffer.write(newValue.text.substring(usedSubstringIndex, newTextLength));

    return TextEditingValue(
      text: newTextBuffer.toString(),
      selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: selectionIndex),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got to solve this problem, checkout this code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class PhoneMaskFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    //Phone Mask: +X (XXX) XXX-XXXX

    //While deleting character get the older value to check if you're deleting not number characters
    final oldValueText = oldValue.text.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'[^0-9]'), '');
    String newValueText = newValue.text;

    //If its same its because you're deleting a non number value so remove the value that you want to delete
    if (oldValueText == newValue.text) {
      newValueText = newValueText.substring(0, newValue.selection.end - 1) + newValueText.substring(newValue.selection.end, newValueText.length);
    }

    final int newTextLength = newValueText.length;

    int selectionIndex = newValue.selection.end;
    int usedSubstringIndex = 0;
    final StringBuffer newText = StringBuffer();

    if (newTextLength >= 1) {
      newText.write('+' + newValueText.substring(0, usedSubstringIndex = 1) + ' (');
      if (newValue.selection.end >= 1) selectionIndex += 3;
    }
    if (newTextLength > 4) {
      newText.write(newValueText.substring(1, usedSubstringIndex = 4) + ') ');
      if (newValue.selection.end >= 4) selectionIndex += 2;
    }
    if (newTextLength > 7) {
      newText.write(newValueText.substring(4, usedSubstringIndex = 7) + '-');
      if (newValue.selection.end >= 7) selectionIndex++;
    }
    // Dump the rest.
    if (newTextLength >= usedSubstringIndex) newText.write(newValueText.substring(usedSubstringIndex));
    return TextEditingValue(
      text: newText.toString(),
      selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: selectionIndex),
    );
  }
}
```